# Change the position of the origin in PyGame coordinate system

Tags: python, coordinates, pygame

I am doing some operations with vectors and physics in PyGame and the default coordinate system is inconvenient for me. Normally the `(0, 0)` point is at the top-left corner, but I would rather that the origin were at the bottom-left corner. I would rather change the coordinate system than converting every single thing I have to draw.

Is it possible to change the coordinate system in PyGame to make it work like this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unfortunately, pygame does not provide any such functionality.  The simplest way to do it would be to have a function to convert coordinates, and use it just before drawing any object.

```
def to_pygame(coords, height):
    """Convert coordinates into pygame coordinates (lower-left => top left)."""
    return (coords[0], height - coords[1])
```

This will take your coordinates and convert them into pygame's coordinates for drawing, given `height`, the height of the window, and `coords`, the top left corner of an object.

To instead use the bottom left corner of the object, you can take the above formula, and subtract the object's height:

```
def to_pygame(coords, height, obj_height):
    """Convert an object's coords into pygame coordinates (lower-left of object => top left in pygame coords)."""
    return (coords[0], height - coords[1] - obj_height)
```

Answer (score 4):

If the objects you're trying to render are vertically symmetrical (like rectangles), you can just flip the screen to get the coordinate system to be the bottom-left, like this:

```
display_surface = pygame.display.get_surface()
display_surface.blit(pygame.transform.flip(display_surface, False, True), dest=(0, 0))
```

You can do the same thing horizontally top/bottom-right. The important methods are documented here:

- [pygame.display.get_surface()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.get_surface)
- [pygame.transform.flip(Surface,
  xbool, ybool)](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.flip)
- [Surface.blit(Surface, dest)](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit)

Answer (score 0):

(⚠️ this example rotates in the other direction you can probably take the point transformation from the other answer and convert -90 to 90)

```
from typing import Sequence
import pygame
from pygame.surface import Surface


class ConvertableScreen:

    def __init__(self, surface: Surface):
        self.surface = surface
        size = surface.get_size()
        self.width = size[0]
        self.height = size[0]

    def blit(self, source: Surface, dest: Sequence[float]):
        # convert points
        new_dest = (self.height-dest[1], dest[0])
        # rotate surface
        rotate90 = pygame.transform.rotate(source, -90)
        self.surface.blit(rotate90, new_dest)
        pass

    def fill(self, col):
        self.surface.fill(col)
```

this is also an approach , but it has the drawback that pygame expects surfaces for some function calls

- youd have to rewrite those to .surface

and also depending on the apis you use you may need to forward additional calls