# Why PyGame coordinate system has its origin at the top-left corner?

Tags: python, graphics, pygame

I've been using PyGame for a while and I have had to make coordinate transformations to change the normal coordinate system used in mathematics (with its origin at the bottom-left corner) to the PyGame coordinate system (with its origin at the top-left corner). I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167329/change-the-position-of-the-origin-in-pygame-coordinate-system) very useful for that.

But I am wondering, why is PyGame using this odd coordinate system?

Comment: Your question is probably better on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ :)

Comment: @IbrahimApachi, Based on the answer of Steve314 I guess that this post is related to computer graphics in general, not only to game development...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not just PyGame - it's an old convention for graphics displays. Many APIs allow you to override and choose your own convention, but even then, they are mapping back to that top-left-corner convention in the background.

The origin of the convention is easy to see for old CRT displays. The raster scan for each frame progressed top-down, with each line scanned left-to-right. Since the scan was done that way, the signal was sent that way, and the pixel buffer in memory was organized that way to allow the hardware to implement a relatively simple and efficient linear scan of memory for each frame.

With LCDs and other newer display technologies, I'm pretty sure the convention it's just for historic reasons - the legacy of a presumably arbitrary decision at one point about how the raster should scan out a picture for TV signals and CRTs many decades ago.